# How to clear the previous appended data on change the dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown and on the change, I am adding the div. This is working for me but the issue is, I am appending the div and when I change the dropdown then the previous div is showing. I have to remove the previous div and display the current div according to dropdown value.

I tried below code. I tried to remove the last append using `$(event.target).closest('.row').html("");` but it's removing all my div including dropdown.

```js
$('.pp_fileStatus').on('change', function(event) {
  if (($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '1') || ($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '3') || ($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '6')) {
    $(event.target).closest('.row').append('<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"> <label>Remark</label><input type="text" name="remark[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');

  } else if (($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '2') || ($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '4') || ($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '5')) {
    $(event.target).closest('.row').append('<div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"> <label>Date</label><input type="text" name="reasonDate[]"  class="form-control datetimepicker"></div></div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"> <label>Remark</label><input type="text" name="remark[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');
  } else if (($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '8') || ($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '9')) {

    $(event.target).closest('.row').append('<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"> <label>Reason</label><input type="text" name="Reason[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');
  } else {
    $(event.target).closest('.row').append('<div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"> <label>Amt</label><input type="text" name="reasonAmt[]"  class="form-control datetimepicker"></div></div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"> <label>Reason</label><input type="text" name="reason[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');

  }
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select name="pp_fileStatus[]" class="form-control multipleselect pp_fileStatus">
        <option value="" disabled selected>File Status</option>
        <option value="1">Status1</option>
        <option value="2">Status2</option>
        <option value="3">Status3</option>
        <option value="4">Status4</option>
        <option value="5">Status5</option>
        <option value="6">Status6</option>
        <option value="7">Status7</option>
        <option value="8">Status8</option>
        <option value="9">Status9</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: $(event.target).closest('.row').empty()

Comment: @Programnik, Let me try this also.

Comment: @Programnik, Nope it's not working. It's removing the all the div including select dropdown,

Comment: just call .empty() on whatever you want to empty.  I cant really work out from your code whats what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.pp_fileStatus').on('change', function(event) {
$(".input-wrapper").remove();
  if (($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '1') || ($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '3') || ($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '6')) {
    $(event.target).closest('.row').append('<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <label>Remark</label><input type="text" name="remark[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');

  } else if (($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '2') || ($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '4') || ($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '5')) {
    $(event.target).closest('.row').append('<div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <label>Date</label><input type="text" name="reasonDate[]"  class="form-control datetimepicker"></div></div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <label>Remark</label><input type="text" name="remark[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');
  } else if (($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '8') || ($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '9')) {

    $(event.target).closest('.row').append('<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <label>Reason</label><input type="text" name="Reason[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');
  } else {
    $(event.target).closest('.row').append('<div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <label>Amt</label><input type="text" name="reasonAmt[]"  class="form-control datetimepicker"></div></div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"> <label>Reason</label><input type="text" name="reason[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');

  }
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select name="pp_fileStatus[]" class="form-control multipleselect pp_fileStatus">
        <option value="" disabled selected>File Status</option>
        <option value="1">Status1</option>
        <option value="2">Status2</option>
        <option value="3">Status3</option>
        <option value="4">Status4</option>
        <option value="5">Status5</option>
        <option value="6">Status6</option>
        <option value="7">Status7</option>
        <option value="8">Status8</option>
        <option value="9">Status9</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If I added one more div above select then it's also hiding that div.

Comment: You will need to wrap the input structure in one container. And remove every element inside that container

Comment: So I have to add  class input-wrapper to the parent div?

Comment: Yes. It will be easily tracked. Or you can change the class name as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.pp_fileStatus').on('change', function(event) {
  if (($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '1') || ($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '3') || ($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '6')) {
    $(".inputappenddiv").html('<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"> <label>Remark</label><input type="text" name="remark[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');

  } else if (($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '2') || ($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '4') || ($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '5')) {
    $(".inputappenddiv").html('<div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"> <label>Date</label><input type="text" name="reasonDate[]"  class="form-control datetimepicker"></div></div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"> <label>Remark</label><input type="text" name="remark[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');
  } else if (($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '8') || ($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '9')) {

    $(".inputappenddiv").html('<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"> <label>Reason</label><input type="text" name="Reason[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');
  } else {
    $(".inputappenddiv").html('<div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"> <label>Amt</label><input type="text" name="reasonAmt[]"  class="form-control datetimepicker"></div></div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"> <label>Reason</label><input type="text" name="reason[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');

  }
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select name="pp_fileStatus[]" class="form-control multipleselect pp_fileStatus">
        <option value="" disabled selected>File Status</option>
        <option value="1">Status1</option>
        <option value="2">Status2</option>
        <option value="3">Status3</option>
        <option value="4">Status4</option>
        <option value="5">Status5</option>
        <option value="6">Status6</option>
        <option value="7">Status7</option>
        <option value="8">Status8</option>
        <option value="9">Status9</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inputappenddiv">
    
  </div>
</div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: give me some time to check your answer.

Comment: I can't use  $(".inputappenddiv").html(') this. because my select dropdown is dyanamically displaying.

Comment: But what relation to displaying inputs with dynamic select?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the children of row except the first child in your case.

```js
$('.pp_fileStatus').on('change', function(event) {
  $(event.target).closest('.row').children().not('.select-div').remove();
  if (($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '1') || ($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '3') || ($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '6')) {
    $(event.target).closest('.row').append('<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"> <label>Remark</label><input type="text" name="remark[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');

  } else if (($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '2') || ($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '4') || ($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '5')) {
    $(event.target).closest('.row').append('<div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"> <label>Date</label><input type="text" name="reasonDate[]"  class="form-control datetimepicker"></div></div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"> <label>Remark</label><input type="text" name="remark[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');
  } else if (($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '8') || ($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '9')) {

    $(event.target).closest('.row').append('<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"> <label>Reason</label><input type="text" name="Reason[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');
  } else {
    $(event.target).closest('.row').append('<div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"> <label>Amt</label><input type="text" name="reasonAmt[]"  class="form-control datetimepicker"></div></div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"> <label>Reason</label><input type="text" name="reason[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');

  }
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="select-div col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select name="pp_fileStatus[]" class="form-control multipleselect pp_fileStatus">
        <option value="" disabled selected>File Status</option>
        <option value="1">Status1</option>
        <option value="2">Status2</option>
        <option value="3">Status3</option>
        <option value="4">Status4</option>
        <option value="5">Status5</option>
        <option value="6">Status6</option>
        <option value="7">Status7</option>
        <option value="8">Status8</option>
        <option value="9">Status9</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have one doubt, If I added one more div above select then? because now it's removing all.? can you assist me this also?

Comment: In my answer, it keeps the parent `div` (with class col-xl-2) of `select` and removes other divs. If you add another div just above `select`. it wont get removed because it is inside the first child div of row. Now, what help do you need? can you elaborate?

Comment: Thanks for the help I tried your code it's working but not 100%. I added one div inside the row and selected the dropdown then it's removing the select dropdown. Can you check from your side also?...my HTML structure is <div class="row"><div class="col">one div here</div> <div class="col"><select></select></div><!--here append div here--></div>

Comment: In  that case just give a class to div containing select and then you can easily select which div to remove and which not. Check my answer I have edited. This will work perfectly for you

Answer (score 0):

```
// Mark what ever you want to do empty here.
// before every change event occurs it will empty your div first then it will append the new one.
$('.pp_fileStatus').on('change', function(event) {
  if (($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '1') || ($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '3') || ($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '6')) {
    $(event.target).closest('.row').append('<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"> <label>Remark</label><input type="text" name="remark[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');

  } else if (($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '2') || ($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '4') || ($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '5')) {
    $(event.target).closest('.row').append('<div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"> <label>Date</label><input type="text" name="reasonDate[]"  class="form-control datetimepicker"></div></div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"> <label>Remark</label><input type="text" name="remark[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');
  } else if (($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '8') || ($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '9')) {

    $(event.target).closest('.row').append('<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"> <label>Reason</label><input type="text" name="Reason[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');
  } else {
    $(event.target).closest('.row').append('<div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"> <label>Amt</label><input type="text" name="reasonAmt[]"  class="form-control datetimepicker"></div></div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"> <label>Reason</label><input type="text" name="reason[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');

  }
});
```

Hope this helps...!!

Comment: May I know what you added in the answer? because I am not able to find it.

Comment: There are two comments above your onchage events,You just need to add an clear div event above your onchange event so ever tym when the event fires those div will be cleared and new divs will be appended